# Laravel/ Lumen formRequest throwing error on submitting all valid values

Tags: php, laravel, lumen

I'm using [this](https://github.com/pearlkrishn/lumen-request-validate) library for `formRequest` feature in my `Lumen` application. I had installed and configured as mentioned in docs but there seems to be somewhere I might be missing or issue in library. Following is my sample code

Validation Class:

```
<?php
namespace App\Http\Requests;

use Pearl\RequestValidate\RequestAbstract;
use Illuminate\Validation\Rule;
use Illuminate\Http\Response;

class CommentFormRequest extends RequestAbstract
{

    /**
     * Determine if the user is authorized to make this request.
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    public function authorize()
    {
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * Get the validation rules that apply to the request.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function rules()
    {

        return [
            'name' => 'required'    
            'title' => 'required|max:255',
            'body' => 'required',
        ];
    }

    /**
     * Get custom messages for validator errors.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function messages()
    {
        return [
            //
        ];
    }
}
```

Controller:

```
<?php
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Requests\CommentFormRequest;

class CommentController extends Controller
{

    public function add(CommentFormRequest $request)
    {
        $request->validated();

       return response()->json(['Success']);
    }       

}
```

When I submit invalid data from postman, valid errors are thrown but when I submit valid data without missing any form field then following error is showing.

```
(1/1) BadMethodCallException
Method App\Http\Requests\CommentFormRequest::validated does not exist.
```

Above error totally making me confusion because if `validated` method is not found then how its throwing error for invalid data? I had tried to debug the issue but as I'm new to `Lumen` nothing I'm able to figure it out to fix this issue.

Comment: What's your Lumen version?

Comment: @Mozammil I'm using lumen 5.7.7

Comment: why there is no nanespace on CommentFormRequest class?

Comment: @SwaroopDeval Its there, corrected now.

Comment: have u registered the service provider in bootstrap/app.php?

Comment: @SwaroopDeval Yes, otherwise it should throw error when I submit invalid data

Comment: Create validator instances using the Validator::make facade method just as you would in Laravel, since all the basic validation rules are available by default.

Answer (score 0):

The reason this is happening is because `validated()` does not exist on the class `CommentFormRequest`.

`CommentFormRequest` extends `RequestAbstract` which in turns extends `Illuminate\Http\Request`, but neither of those classes have an implementation for `validated()`.

I understand the confusion comes from the fact that Laravel has a `$request->validated()` method which outputs the validated fields, but that is something specific to Laravel's Form Request. As you can see from its [API](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.5/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/FormRequest.php#L173), `validated()` is defined there instead.

There's also an important notice on Lumen's [documentation](https://lumen.laravel.com/docs/5.7/validation).

> Form requests are not supported by Lumen. If you would
>   like to use form requests, you should use the full Laravel framework.

Comment: thanks for your answer. Yes, I also mentioned in my question that `Lumen` doesn't have `FormRequest` feature due to that reason only I'm using [this](https://packagist.org/packages/pearl/lumen-request-validate) library. So these libraries won't provide that feature at all.

Comment: Like I said `validated()` is a method defined in Laravel's [FormRequest](https://laravel.com/api/5.7/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/FormRequest.html#method_validated). The library that you are using extends `Illuminate\Http\Request` which does not have that implementation. See [this](https://github.com/pearlkrishn/lumen-request-validate/blob/master/src/RequestAbstract.php).

Comment: is there any other approach to fix this issue?

Comment: You could try to find another library that has has an implementation for it. Perhaps this [one](https://github.com/urameshibr/lumen-form-request).

Comment: I had tried that library also, I'm facing same issue

Comment: Yes, I can't vouch for the library. I haven't used it but I did see that the author was trying to implement it.